# How to use Resultreceiver and AlarmManager together?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

According to [**this article**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services), if I need to implement auto deleting certain rows (older than current time) from my database only when certain activity is open, I have to use ResultReceiver:

> ResultReceiver - Generic callback interface for sending results between service and activity. If your service only needs to connect with its parent application in a single place, use this approach.

and AlarmManager:

> Trigger at a specified time in the future or at a recurring interval

But i faced with problem that i dont know how to use AlarmManager with ResultReceiver. I mean i dont understand how to call my IntentService from Activity.

In my Intent service i have something like that:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Inside onHandleIntent");
        ResultReceiver rec = intent.getParcelableExtra(IntentConstants.UPDATE_REMINDERS_SERVICE_RECEIVER);
        int rowsDeleted = notificationService.deleteAllOld(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(IntentConstants.UPDATE_REMINDERS_SERVICE_NOTIFICATIONS_DELETED, "Rows deleted: " + rowsDeleted);
        // Here we call send passing a resultCode and the bundle of extras
        rec.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);

    }
```

And in Activity:

```
// Starts the IntentService
    public void onStartService() {
        Log.d("UpdateRemindersLog", "Inside onStartService");
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, UpdateRemindersService.class);
        i.putExtra(IntentConstants.UPDATE_REMINDERS_SERVICE_RECEIVER, remindersReceiver);
        startService(i);
    }
```

I've tried to implement AlarmManager inside onStartService method but it doesn't work. I thought it's gonna be like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateRemindersReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.UPDATE_REMINDERS_SERVICE_RECEIVER, remindersReceiver);
// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, UpdateRemindersService.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 10*1000, pendingIntent);
```

So, can someone to explain me how i can implement AlarmManager with IntentService?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target of the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` call needs to be a broadcast receiver, as the method suggests. The `AlarmManager` only works with `Intent`s for those.

So you need to add a broadcast receiver that handles the `AlarmManager`'s signal and then starts your service:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Start your service here
    }
}
```

Also, remember to register your receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, like this (inside your `application` tag):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

And when you create your `Intent` you should now target your new receiver class (`AlarmReceiver.class`).

Comment: I just found out that IntentService and AlarmManager are both "launchers". So my code was stupid as hell. But thx man for help any way!